# HtmlEmail/Zurb Ink - How to Customise Font Colors So that they correctly appear in Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email, zurb-ink

I'm using Zurb Ink to create HTML emails. It's working fine, and the framaework is great to use, but I'm having a problem customising font colors in outlook.

As I understand it, fonts styles shoudl be set at TD level for outlook. Is this correct? I've tried applying this, and the email looks fine everywhere except outlook.

Any input on this is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone happens to find this, the best I could do to get around the problem was to colour the text with a font tag. Not ideal, but it works!